# Issue with Cron Job and PHP Script

Tags: php, cron

I am having a difficult situation here that I am trying to debug.

I have a **scraper** script, which has a file locking to prevent multiple instances, and also have a block on non cli executions.

I have set it in cron to run every minute. The **scraper** does some database functions, and outputs statuses to 2 text files, which I monitor using jquery page so I see things live.

So I can see if the script is idle or running, I can see the last worked string, and details.I also do a check in the database to see the pending no. of sites that **scraper** should handle.

The situation now is, I see the pending no. of sites reducing, but the check says script is idle, and there is nothing fed into the 2 text files.

When I try `ps aux | grep php` I see the 2 lines.

```
root      3159  0.0  0.0   4392   664 ?        Ss   17:57   0:00 /bin/sh -c php /var/www/html/workers/scraper.php
root      3160  0.0  1.5 298100 15824 ?        S    17:57   0:00 php /var/www/html/workers/scraper.php
```

And when I try to run it myself, using php scraper.php it runs ( It shouldnt be, because the file lock should now fail), and I get it.

```
root      3159  0.0  0.0   4392   664 ?        Ss   17:57   0:00 /bin/sh -c php /var/www/html/workers/scraper.php
root      3160  0.0  1.5 298100 15824 ?        S    17:57   0:00 php /var/www/html/workers/scraper.php
root      3295  0.0  1.4 297852 15208 pts/2    S+   18:11   0:00 php scraper.php
```

Anyway idea whats going on? I have been struggling to find whats wrong. In short, the cron actually does the work and do the **scraping** , but it doesnt care about filelocking, or outputting statuses to text files, which looks so weird.

Here is the code :

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
if(PHP_SAPI !== 'cli' || isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) {
    exit('cli only');
}
//get the site lists.
require_once("writedata.php");
require_once("dbconnect.php");

//set file lock to get script status
$file = fopen("lock.txt","w+");
// exclusive lock
if (flock($file, LOCK_EX | LOCK_NB))
{
    // Grab lock. Continue work.
    echo "Started Running";
//ALL THE MAIN WORK HAPPENS HERE.
$sql = "SELECT site FROM `sites` WHERE status=0 LIMIT 2500";
$result = $db->query($sql);

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    $site=$row['site'];
    file_put_contents("errors.txt", $site);

//Scraper functions and parsing functions removed.

}
}
else{
    echo "Script already running";
    exit;
}
```

Comment: I assumed it wasnt problems of the code, but something related to cron and so. Thats why I didnt add any code. I have added the main parts now.

Comment: @RyanVincent - Two cron jobs shouldnt be processing the same site because 2 crons should be running because we have a file lock. That is the expected way to work. And just incase if 2 crons process the same site, the second one will fail entering datas to the database because of a q `unique` constraint. No, I am not using `transactions` because the script doesnt need that precision. I usually use `transactions` where users,orders, etc are involved.

Comment: I think we are diverting too much here mate :(. I want the script to respect the file locking and work the `file_put_contents` which doesnt work when it is run by cron.

Comment: Currently when it is run by cron, the file doesnt get locked, and there is no output to `file_put_contents` but everything else works. Since there is no locking,I can also run another instance. Wondering why this happens.